# minimum ratio of the shortest isoform to the longest one derived from one same parent gene

Tags: gene, isoforms

I want to know what is the minimum percentage of the shortest isoform/transcript to the longest one that derived from the same parent gene? Does it have organism specificity? What is the function of the shortest isoform?

Because I want to filter the gtf file from cuffmerge. One consideration is that the very short isoform maybe artificial or random transcripts that should be filtered.

From this page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPgm.png), the CREB gene has been manually annotated and included a processed transcripts only 84bp, while the longest transcript of this gene is 8532bp. So the ratio is < 0.01; However, this transcript is not coding sequences. I also plot the minimum ratio distribution in human GENCODE v22 data.

[image: minimum ratio distribution in human]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPgm.png) vega.sanger.ac.uk/Homo_sapiens/Transcript/Summary?g=OTTHUMG00000097081;r=7:28724300-28726731;t=OTTHUMT00000327948

Best,

Pengcheng

Comment: maybe you are looking for __proportion__? That is ratio of isoform A to isoform B

Comment: thank you @aandreev, I have updated the content accordingly.

Comment: Splice product that short cannot be considered an isoform. If you are interested in splice products then you can have a look at miRNA arising from intron of the host gene.

Comment: @WYSIWYG thank you. I have disregarded the transcripts without annotated as "protein_coding". Yes, as you suggested, miRNA can be produced from intron, so the processed transcripts that detected in RNAseq potentially miRNA sequences.